# Why Schannel fails to receive handshake from the server?

Tags: windows, git, ssl, openssl, tls

When I'm trying to pull from our git server I get this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'xxx': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
>   in connection to xxx

When this happened before I was able to solve it by simply restoring the system but this time my system restore points got deleted for some reason, and I can't do that either.

So this happens because something in my system settings related to SSL changes and I don't know why.

I have tried installing git to use windows cert. store instead of OpenSSL and I got this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'xxx': schannel: failed to receive handshake,
>   SSL/TLS connection failed

Same problem, different error message. The server is not sending back a hello message after the client hello. I thought this might happen because none of the cipher suites that I'm sending the server in the client hello message are supported by the server. So I've tried [configuring a group policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt808163(v=vs.85).aspx) and put the cipher suite the server is using first in order. But it didn't make any difference.

I am able to connect the git server's site through the browser. So my question is, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: did you happen to get anywhere with this?  I have the EXACT same problem.

Comment: yes, I formatted my pc :) I spent a day figuring this out but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Well, in case you come upon this again, I uninstalled git and deleted my .gitconfig file, and started from scratch.  Seemed to fix the problem, who knows.